# Angularjs directive: how to find an element by dynamic id, and modify template

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to generate a form dynamically, based on a template which in turn has some dynamic properties.

I'm getting close, but having trouble retrieving a container element.

This is the directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
    template: "<div> <label>{{Field.Name}} <div id='{{Field.Name}}_Container'></div> </label></div>",
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        Field: "=fieldInfo",
        FieldData:"="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        var input = "<input type='" + scope.Field.Type + "' data-ng-model='FieldData[" + scope.Field.Name + "]' />";
        var inputEl = angular.element(input);
        var container = angular.element("#" + scope.Field.Name + "_Container"); // Doesn't work
        container.append(inputEl);
    }
}

});
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.Fields = [
      { Name: "field1", Type: "text", Data:null },
      { Name: "field2", Type: "number", Data:null }
    ];

     $scope.FieldData = {}; //{fieldname: fielddata}
}
```

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <my-directive data-ng-repeat="field in Fields" data-field-info="field">
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

Basically I have fields descriptor objects, and need to generate a form based on that.
I'm not quite sure how to reference a container object - does template has to be compiled before linking somehow ?

Also, I'm actually using templateUrl, if that matters.

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eugenelt/EAW4F/2/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) the compile to html template. Also, you can use `element` in the `link` function to access the outer `div` in your template.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function ($compile) {
    return {
        template: "<div> <label>{{Field.Name}} <div id='{{Field.Name}}_Container'></div> </label></div>",
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            Field: "=fieldInfo",
            FieldData:"="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var input = "<input type='" + scope.Field.Type + "' data-ng-model='FieldData[" + scope.Field.Name + "]' />";
            var html = $compile(input)(scope);
            element.find('div').append(html);
        }
    }
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/5LqUL/).

Comment: +1 But future readers should note that element.find() is recursive, so if the template was more complicated than this, you would need use another approach (like element.children()).

Comment: Changed it. The point was to use 'element' in the link function

Comment: I think your first way was the best in this case. Side note: I don't think jqLite supports a search value in `element.children` like jQuery does, but I could be wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I assumed it worked, since i didnt get any error ;)

Comment: Any way I could pull that container div by id ? I've tried to compile element, but no luck:  var container = $compile(elem)(scope); var el = angular.element("#" + scope.Field.Name + "_Container", container);

Comment: Try --> var html = $compile(input)(scope); var el = angular.element("#" + scope.Field.Name + "_Container"); el.append(html);

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. element doesn't have it's id compiled yet. If i call --> var a = $compile(elem)(scope);console.log(a.html()); -- it returns null for some reason.  Not an issue in this case, really, but with more complex template it would be nice to be able to target specific element.